# how to build spring-data-mongodb use maven

Tags: maven, spring-data-mongodb

I pull spring-data-mongodb on github:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb. i import the project into my eclipse, but there is many erros when maven build. so i open my cmd, and execute mvn package:

```
D:\codes\owncodes\github\spring-data-mongodb>mvn package
```

there are erros:
     **Could not find artifact org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:pom:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT**

But how i find the org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:pom:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT? i find spring-data-build, but i meet similar questtion when build  spring-data-build. I now have no idea how to deal with the errors. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean `similar question`?

Comment: `The project org.springframework.data.build:spring-data-parent:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (D:\codes\owncodes\github\spring-data-build\parent\pom.xml) has 2 errors
  Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:5.0.0.RC2 from/to mirror (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot): Connect to repo.spring.io:443 [repo.spring.io/35.186.232.213] failed: Connection timed out: connect @ line 581, column 16 -> [Help 2]
  'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ line 629, column 15`

Comment: i find the pom in https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot, but i don't know why mvn tell can't not find. it is probleam of proxy?

Comment: Yes. The reason is in your connection to the repo. Please show the related part (repo settings & proxy settings) in your pom and mvn settings.

Comment: i do experience the same error, trying to build spring boot 2.1 code. comes right from mvn clean. do i need a proxy or what to access those 35.186.232.213? pinging it timed out.